# Use an variable for a query.column assignment instead of an explicitly defined name

Tags: sql, coldfusion

The working query below is used for the next code section that fails:

```
<cfquery name="q_GetAnalyticsSect" datasource="#THIS.DSN#">
    SELECT
        <cfloop from="1" to="11" index="i">
            SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = #thisYear# AND MONTH = #i# THEN VIEWS ELSE 0 END) #monthArr[i]#,
        </cfloop>
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = #thisYear# AND MONTH = 12 THEN VIEWS ELSE 0 END) December
    FROM
        SYSTEM_ANALYTICS
</cfquery>
```

**NOTE:**

A. The monthArr just has each month name (January through December) using the number.

B. The SUM(CASE..) statements are executed as:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = 2023 AND MONTH = 1 THEN VIEWS ELSE 0 END) January,
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = 2023 AND MONTH = 2 THEN VIEWS ELSE 0 END) February, 
…… through December
```

After the query, I am attempting to retrieve the value from each query column using the process below:

```
<cfset sectionArr = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfloop query="q_GetAnalyticsSect">
    <cfloop from="1" to="12" index="i">
        <cfset sectionArr[i] = q_GetAnalyticsSect.monthArr(i)> 
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

However, I get the error:

**Element MONTHARR is undefined in Q_GETANALYTICSSECT**

I could list out all 12 statements:

```
<cfset sectionArr[1] = q_GetAnalyticsSect.January)>
<cfset sectionArr[2] = q_GetAnalyticsSect.February>
....
<cfset sectionArr[12] = q_GetAnalyticsSect.December>
```

but I would like the logic to work for other projects.

It appears that ColdFusion is explicitly using the array variable name (.monthArr(i)) instead of the array value (January..December)!

Therefore I need the code to use the actual array value as the query column.

How can I do that?

Comment: Function `queryname.getColumnList()` returns an array of the query columns.  That should simplify things for you.

Comment: For one, `monthArr(i)`: you're calling `monthArr` as a function, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're trying to do, but this should produce an array similar to what you've listed:

```
<cfset sectionArr = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfloop query="q_GetAnalyticsSect">
    <cfloop from="1" to="12" index="i">
        <cfset sectionArr[i] = "q_GetAnalyticsSect." & monthAsString(i)> 
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```